# Negative Binomial convolution

Tags: statistics, convolution, negative-binomial

I've seen a couple of questions where some users provide some help on how to calculate the convolution of two independent variables $X\sim NB(r,p)$ and $Y\sim NB(s,p)$ [link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035210/convolution-of-negative-binomial-distribution), [link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054048/negative-binomial-distribution-sum-of-two-random-variables). However they always stop the demonstration when they arrive to:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^k {j+r-1 \choose j}\cdot {k-j +s-1 \choose k-j}={k+r+s-1 \choose k}$$

How can this be proved?

Thank you very much